# Variable in LIKE clause

Tags: sql

I have some data in a table called Addresses:

```
HouseNumber Address
32          32 The Street
1           2 The Way
4           4 The Street
5           5 The Street
```

I am trying to find the House Numbers that are incorrect.
I thought the query below would return '2 The Way' but it does not.

```
select Address
FROM   Addresses
WHERE  HouseNumber NOT LIKE '%' + Address + '%'
```

Is there any easy way to do this like in the query above, or do I have to write a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must swap `Address` and `HouseNumber`. Also, because your `Address` starts with `HouseNumber` you can make your query mode correct and also sragable.

```
select Address
FROM   Addresses
WHERE  Address NOT LIKE HouseNumber + ' %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
select Address FROM Addresses WHERE Address NOT LIKE '%' + HouseNumber + '%'
```

??

Comment: No, because that would give a false positive for `4` and `44 High Street`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try it the other way around

```
select Address FROM Addresses WHERE Address NOT LIKE '% ' + HouseNumber + ' %'
```

This way it will try to match '1' (housenumber) with '2 the way'. Rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the house number from the address, and check it against the house number column (not tested):

```
select Address
from   Addresses
where  cast(Housenumber as int) != cast(left(Address, instr(Address, " ")-1) as int)
```

This assumes the house number is always at the beginning of the address, and there is a space between the house number and the rest of the address.